# User interface for c++

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, mfc, clr

I have a program in c++ on visual studio'10. And have decided to create a simple user interface for it on VS'10

My question is, confusion raises when choosing among MFC, CLR, Win32 etc. which one should I go for implementing my UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraints of your choices and the fact that you've already chosen C++, then I would go with MFC.  Had you chosen C, I would have told you Win32.  Had you chosen C#, I probably would have recommended WPF.